# Store the scanned value in array and find the largest value in Android

Tags: android, arrays, ibeacon-android

In my Beacon application I am getting different values of RSSI through beacon.getRSSI(). Now I want to get the max value of RSSI of all the scanned beacons. So I thought the possible solution will be array. Can anyone helpout how to do this?

Comment: Your question is more about basic java than ibeacons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the Beacon objects into a Collection (List, Set), then use `Collections.max` to get the beacon with the highest RSSI. [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator))

```
List<Beacon> beacons = new ArrayList<Beacon>();
// add all the beacons
beacons.add(beacon);

(...)

Beacon maxBeacon = Collections.max(beacons, new Comparator<Beacon>(){
    public int compare(Beacon b1, Beacon b2) {
        return Integer.compare(b1.getRSSI(), b2.getRSSI);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ahve made Collection list but how can I add the beacon object as I am getting values by scanning!!

Comment: Introduce a field `private List<Beacon> beacons` and supposedly you have callback `onBeaconFound(...)` where you then call the `beacons.add(beacon)`.

Comment: I have done that but it is asking to initialize the object. So what value should i initialize to each Beacon object.

Comment: Maybe it asks to init the list? `private List<Beacon> beacons = new ArrayList<Beacon>();`

Comment: No it asks to initialize the Beacon object! The list I have initalized and is working.

Comment: In your ranging listener just call `this.beacons.addAll(beacons)`. Or name your field allBeacons, then call `allBeacons.addAll(beacons)`.

Comment: But then how would I compare the min values through 'beacons' object as according to your code there will be comparison b1, b2,..!

Comment: `Collections.max`/ `.min` will take care of that for you.